# Creating a Timestamp from a URL string

Tags: php

I have read the manual - but can't seem to find what I need. I don't need the actual date - I need the date I tell it is from the URL

This is what I have currently:

```
//create search string for posts date check
if($Day <= 9) {//ensure day is dual digit
$fix = 0; 
$Day = $fix . $Day;
}
$Day = preg_replace("/00/", "/0/", $Day);
$date = $_GET["Year"];
$date .= "-";
$date .= $_GET["Month"];
$date .= "-";
$date .= $_GET["Day"];


$currently = mktime (0,0,0,$Month,$Day,$Year,0); //create a timestamp from date components in url feed

//create display date from timestamp
$dispdate = date("l, j F Y",$currently);
```

When I echo $date it reads correctly for the variable string supplied in the URL but $dispdate always returns the current day that it actually is today. I need $currently to be the timestamp of the date in the URL too.

Comment: I understand neither English nor PHP are your native languages but this question is unreadable. If you want to parse information from current URL you must provide sample data, expected output and some code that makes sense (not a random snippet where variables pop up from nowhere).

Comment: What is $Day and where does it get set?  You use it in the `if` before it gets set.

Comment: What is the content of $Day before you this code is executed? Did you check if your $_GET variables actually contain what you expect? How does your called URL look like?

Comment: How does your URL look like? I guess you don't have to dual-digit the day. But `str_pad` would be the nicer solution.

Comment: I apologize if I am clumsy asking my questions - I have limited knowledge here.

Comment: My url looks like this: /MyBooks/dailies.php?Year=2015&Month=11&Day=28

Comment: well one thing wrong here is that your $currently variable doesn't actually use the values passed through GET parameters, or you're not showing us the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to construct a valid, readable datestring from the GET parameters. Use

`$currently = strtotime($date)`.

It will return a timestamp that you can use to create the `$dispdate` like you already do with the `date` function.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like not all the OP's code was posted, so this is based on what is known.

In the line:

```
mktime (0,0,0,$Month,$Day,$Year,0)
```

You are using variables that aren't shown to us (so we must assume are not being set to anything). Above this line you are building a "$date" variable with the URL parameters. This is what should be used in your mktime function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Datetime object, pass the given parameters and format the output anyway you want.

```
<?php

//replace with GET params
$year = 2015;
$month = 10;
$day = 01;

$datetime = new Datetime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day);

echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');

?>
```